# Remote desktop not visible over LAN when using VNC (SSH tunnel confirmed to be working)

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc

There are two machines on LAN: `user@intel`(server) and `greg@dom`(client) - both Xubuntu 18.04.

The server installation/deployment was done using:

```
user@intel:~$ sudo apt-get update
user@intel:~$ sudo apt install tightvncserver
user@intel:~$ vncserver

New 'X' desktop is intel:1

Starting applications specified in /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/user/.vnc/intel:1.log

user@intel:~$ ps -ef | grep vnc
user     16697     1  0 15:39 pts/15   00:00:00 Xtightvnc :1 -desktop X -auth /home/user/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 -rfbwait 120000 -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ -co /etc/X11/rgb
user     18546 28658  0 15:41 pts/15   00:00:00 grep --color=auto vnc
```

The SSH tunnel also works from the client:

```
greg@dom:~$ ps -ef | grep ssh
greg     24271     1  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00 ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l user intel
```

When using the `VNC - VNC viewer` mode in Remmina from the client, I get the following after entering the VNC password:

[image]

Comment: Try this command : `vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1`.

Comment: @harrymc I stopped the previous vncserver and started it using the new command however there was no difference when trying to login from the client.

Comment: Here are various posts with various solutions relating to the problem which you could try: [post1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800302/vncserver-grey-screen-ubuntu-16-04-lts), [post2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924139/vnc-grey-screen-with-xubuntu-17-04) and [post3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127466/blank-screen-with-vnc-server).